# Converting to Sturm-Liouville using integration factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, sturm-liouville

I know this type of question has been asked before, but I cannot find information on this specific form I am supposed to be using. We are being asked to convert a second-order DE

\begin{equation*}\alpha(x)y'' + \beta(x)y′ + \gamma(x)y = \lambda y
\end{equation*}

to Sturm-Liouville form using the integration factor

\begin{equation*}
F(x) = \exp\left(
\int \frac{[\beta(u) − \alpha'(u)]}{\alpha(u)}\right)
\end{equation*}

I've been looking for at least 3 hours for information regarding this specific I.F. and I can't find anything. Can someone please point me in the right direction or provide a starting point? Thank you

Comment: What information are you looking for?  It might help to note that your integrating factor is equivalent to $\alpha(x)^{-1} \exp(\int \beta/\alpha \,\mathrm dx)$.

Comment: @messenger I did end up figuring that out and was able to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the "$u$" should be a $x$:
$$
   \exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx-\int\frac{\alpha'(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)=\exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)\frac{1}{\alpha(x)}
$$
Then multiply your original equation
$$
    \alpha(x)y''(x)+\beta(x)y'(x)+\gamma(x)y(x)=\lambda y(x)
$$
by the expression on the right of the first line to obtain:
$$
     \exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)\frac{1}{\alpha(x)}(\alpha(x)y''(x)+\beta(x)y'(x)+\gamma(x)y(x)-\lambda y(x))=0 \\
    \exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)\left(y''(x)+\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}y'(x)+\frac{\gamma(x)}{\alpha(x)}y(x)-\frac{\lambda}{\alpha(x)}y(x)\right)=0
$$
This gives a Sturm-Liouville form that needs to be broken across a line:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\right]+\frac{\gamma(x)}{\alpha(x)}\exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)y(x)= \\=\frac{\lambda}{\alpha(x)}\exp\left(\int\frac{\beta(x)}{\alpha(x)}dx\right)y(x).
$$

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: @dakotakeblbeck - You're welcome.